# 32-bit application (timeEdition) stopped working on new hardware

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, multiarch

I got a new laptop and copied the partitions of the old harddisk onto the new one (/ and /home) and everything works, except 1 application that won't start anymore.

It is an old (2009) time tracker called timeEdition (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/timeedition/timeEdition1.1.6-linux.tgz) which I have been using on various Ubuntu versions from somewhere around version 9 or 10 up till 13.10 x64. So far, I always managed to get it working, also on 64-bit architecture, first with the help of ia32-libs etc., on 13.10 with the default multiarch and libstdc++5.

Now nothing has changed, as far as I can tell, except the new hardware, but it refuses to start, giving this error:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I googled for answers and found esp. this thread, but to no avail: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1956802

I also tried a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on the new machine, but after resolving all dependencies shown with 'ldd timeEdition' I get to the exact same situation.

Any ideas what can be the cause and how to solve this?

Comment: I also facing similar issue that state:  Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(setup:14189): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(setup:14189): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

any luck here?

Comment: No, sorry. I spent quite some time trying to resolve it and followed various paths and leads, but no solution and I ran out of clues. I ended up finding another application to my time tracking (now happily using Hamster).

Answer (score 0):

following work for 64 bit Ubuntu 13.10 system:

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 (run 32 bit lib for 64 bit system)

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libidn11:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libxtst6:i386
```